# Heroku Platform API - Domain Create Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to create custom domains in Heroku through a controller action in my rails app. For now I just have a method in a controller to create the domains. I've been messing around with it for a few hours, but I keep getting either an unprocessable entity error or a 404 not found error.

Here's my code:

```
def create_custom_domain
  heroku = PlatformAPI.connect_oauth('[TOKEN]')
  heroku.domain.create('[APPNAME]', { hostname: "[www.abc.com]", sni_endpoint: "" })
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

I've also tried making the value of the sni_endpoint parameter `null` because the docs say it's nullable, but that doesn't work either.

I've been using the Heroku api docs and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Here are the docs I've been looking at:

https://github.com/heroku/platform-api

https://heroku.github.io/platform-api/PlatformAPI/Domain.html

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain

Comment: Does the App already exist? If not you are going to need to create that first. It is difficult to tell from the post specifically what is going on as I don't see anything glaring here but 404 suggests that something is missing. Is there a full error message you can provide? This [Section](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#errors) suggests that an error message will be returned.